# php mod rewrite .htaccess ignore directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What rule should i set, to make the mod_rewrite ignore the directory "public" completely?
By that, I mean, the files should be accessible within it, but if the file does not exist, a server error page should come up with something like, FORBIDDEN, or FILE NOT FOUND what ever. I do not need custom error pages or stuff like that. I simply want the "public" to behave like there is no mod_rewrite at all.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My file structure is

```
/system/
/application/
/public/
```

I want the folder public to behave, like there are no rewrite rules set at all, completely ignore it.

**edit**

That's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(public)($|/) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I already had this .htaccess in the /public/ folder:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

I've tried all the different answers above (and a ton from google). I've tried to mix 'em up what so ever.

My folders:

```
/system/
/application/
/public/ 
/public/.htaccess #RewriteEngine off
/public/favicon.ico
/index.php
```

Below are the url with results I'm getting:

```
/public/favicon.ico -> I get the favicon
/public/faviDon.ico -> I get the index.php (without mod rewrite you would get "not found")
/public/ -> I get the index.php (without mod rewrite "forbidden")
```

So it still does rewrite urls, if the file was not found, or upon accessing a folder directly.

Can you se it?

Thank you very much for effort guys! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: if 'public' is the web root, then it is 'ignored' as far as the urls of your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I completely setup your files on my machine

```
//  /.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(public)($|/) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

.htaccess in the public folder:

```
//  /public/.htaccess

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine off
```

This disables rewriting like you wanted.

```
/public/                 -> 403 Forbidden
/public/favicon.ico      -> 200 File found
/public/not-existing.ext -> 404 File not found
```

Do you have a index.php in you public folder?
Maybe you could remove that one..

What kind of machine your testing on?

I tested it on Linux + Apache 2 + PHP5.3

I can give you more support in the afternoon (my time +2 GMT)

**EDIT 2**

When I remove this line from /.htaccess is still works

```
RewriteRule ^(public)($|/) - [L,NC]
```

Everything is handled by the .htaccess in the public folder.

Maybe it's a caching problem in your browser. Try a different browser/clean up history/install app to remove cache.. (depending on what browser you're using)

Comment: everything works well, exept: access the folder public/ redirects to index.php (instead of FORBIDDEN). accessing a not existing file within the directory redirects to index.php (instead of FILE NOT FOUND)

Comment: I'm going crazy on this :(

Comment: +1 as is a quite better solution than mine. @maximkott do you have index.php in `/public/`? is it redirects to root index.php? If so please show me full your .htaccess file with Ferry's answer

Comment: I've did it just as you said... Didn't work for me. public directory is still being rewritten. I play around a bit with your solution, and post a feedback!

Comment: No luck till now... I'me gone, will be back at around 18.00 GMT+1. So can't answer to your posts, just that you know. Have a nice day))

Comment: I think it's a special kind of server konfiguration that's causing this issue. Setting proper ErrorDocument 404 and ErrorDocument 403 in the .htaccess in the public directory did the trick.