# Add Folder Exception to htaccess File

Tags: .htaccess

I currently use the following .htaccess file that redirects every page on my site to the index.php page.

I would like to make an exception for my /images/ folder and all the files in it.

How can I ignore all of the files in that folder?  Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/$ /index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^.* index.php
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mod rewrite .htaccess ignore directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488186/php-mod-rewrite-htaccess-ignore-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead of your :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(images)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*/$ /index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^.* index.php
```

or just create a new .htaccess file in the images derectory  with this line in it :

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Comment: @user3303540 you welcome , you can make my answer as right alswer ;)